# Spring+Jersey getting error at api call

Tags: java, spring, jersey-1.0

I'm getting following error while calling API.

```
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:393)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.aqinsights.API.getUsers(API.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:384)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:101)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

my api request handler file look like this

```
package com.aqinsights;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Path("/API")
@Component
public class API {
    @Autowired
    IEmpDao dao;


    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public  String getUsers() {
        System.out.println("reached");
        //System.out.println(dao.getEmployees());
        List<Emp> list=dao.getEmployees();
        System.out.println(list);
        return "Welcome";
    }

}
```

spring-servlet.xml look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ights"></context:component-scan>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ds"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=trainning"></property>
        <property name="username" value="**"></property>
        <property name="password" value="****"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="com.ights.EmpDao">
        <property name="template" ref="jt"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <display-name>SpringCrudDemo</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.aqinsights</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

IEmpDao.java file look like this.

```
package com.ights;

import java.util.List;

public interface IEmpDao {

    int save(Emp p);
    int update(Emp p);
    int delete(int id);
    Emp getEmpById(int id);
    List<Emp> getEmployees();
}
```

and i'm calling http://localhost:8082/SpringCrudDemo/rest/API/users

kindly help as am newbie at spring+jersy

Comment: Your are mixing two technologies. You do not need @RestController annotation if you are using Jersey. You can not directly inject DAO in jersey class. Therefore you are getting null pointer exception. Here is good example of Jersey with Spring [Link](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/)

Comment: still not working

Comment: Are you using Jersey v1 as you have tagged your question? If so, you should not reference org.glassfish.jersey... packages as they belong to jersey 2